# How does `extends` work internally in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Why does `extends` work differently in these two situations? I noticed the `extends` works like an iterator with the generic types, but I'd like to know more about why that is not the case in situation 1? What makes the difference and why it works in this way?

```
// situation 1
type A = 1 | 2 | 3
type B = 1 | 2
type C = A extends B ? never : A // returns 1 | 2 | 3
// situation 2
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T
type D = Exclude<A, B>; // returns 3
```

Comment: Can you first confirm that you either know, or don't know, _why_ `A extends B` is `false`?

Comment: BTW, your code (as-is) gives me an error because you're redefining `Exclude`, which is a built-in utility type.

Comment: I don't think my understanding on "why A extends B is false" is correct because I expect it to work the same as in situation 2

Comment: Yep, my definition of `Exclude` is the same as the built-in utility type, you can comment it out if that's causing an error